# Scaling data using MinMaxScaler causing unhashable type error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I’m trying to scale my data with a MinMaxScaler.  I’m using sklearn.  When I try to fit and transform the dataframe, I’m getting the error message below.  I would post some code but it’s identical to the first couple lines of the error message.  I would also post some sample data, but my dataframe has about 1 million records, and 700 columns.  Does anyone know what the issue might be?

```
Error:

    171     scaler = MinMaxScaler()
--> 172     s_df[list_cont]=scaler.fit_transform(s_df[list_cont])
    173 
    174     return s_df

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3659 
   3660         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
-> 3661         if broadcast and key in self.columns and value.ndim == 1:
   3662             if (not self.columns.is_unique or
   3663                     isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex)):

/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __contains__(self, key)
   3918     @Appender(_index_shared_docs['contains'] % _index_doc_kwargs)
   3919     def __contains__(self, key):
-> 3920         hash(key)
   3921         try:
   3922             return key in self._engine

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the `sklearn.preprocessor.MinMaxScaler`.

As you can see, all the error messages are from `pandas`, not `sklearn`.

In the line `s_df[list_cont]=scaler.fit_transform(s_df[list_cont])`,
`list_cont` contains a `set` and hence `pandas` complains that it cannot select columns.